# Given point before and after rotation at given axis calculate the angle of rotation

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I have a point at 2d space in only positive x and y axis, point P(x1, y1) is rotated along axis point C(x3, y3) to reach at point P2(x2, y2).

Now I just need to calculate the angle of rotation.

If possible please share simplified formula along with the details.

Refer this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkP0D.jpg) provided for clarity

Thanks

Comment: Make sense thanks. Could you put this on answer so i could upVote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\arctan_2(y_2-y_c,x_2-x_c)-\arctan_2(y_1-y_c,x_1-x_c)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Take the two vectors:
$$
\vec p_1=P_1C=(x_1-x_3,y_1-y_3)^T \qquad \vec p_2=P_2C=(x_2-x_3,y_2-y_3)^T
$$

do you know that the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of these vectors is:
$$
\vec p_1 \cdot \vec p_2=|\vec p_1||\vec p_2| \cos \theta$$
where $ \theta$ is the angle between the two vectors?

---

$$
\vec p_1 \cdot \vec p_2=(x_1-x_3)(x_2-x_3)+(y_1-y_3)(y_2-y_3)
$$
$$
|\vec p_1 |=\sqrt{(x_1-x_3)^2+(y_1-y_3)}
$$
$$
|\vec p_2 |=\sqrt{(x_2-x_3)^2+(y_2-y_3)}
$$
$$
\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{\vec p_1 \cdot \vec p_2}{|\vec p_1||\vec p_2|} \right)
$$

Comment: I need a **formula** to calculate the *θ*. This I know but since i am not in touch with math since 6 years i need simplified version. With simplified I mean in not in vector form

Comment: Use the componets of the vectors as I've added to my answer.